How to add Horizontal Grow Animation to the rectangle
I am able to grow the rectangle horizontally and vertically via following code.
But I want to grow the rectangle only horizontally. How can I do that?
Sub Macro1()

'Delete all slides
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Delete
Next i

'Add a blank slide
ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutBlank

'Add a Rectangle
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50)
    .Name = "myRectangle"
End With

'Add a GrowShrink effect to the myRectangle
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("myRectangle"), EffectId:=msoAnimEffectGrowShrink)
    .EffectParameters.Size = 150
    'The following code doesnt work
    '.EffectParameters.Direction = msoAnimDirectionHorizontal
End With

End Sub

Please note that I am open other solutions without using msoAnimEffectGrowShrink effect.

How about just changing its width?

Duplicate the slide, make the rectangle narrower on the first slide, wider on the second. Apply a Morph transition. No animation or VBA required.
